# How to display the custom attribute on product page in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-attributes, rwd-theme

I am working rwd theme customization> I am trying to add a new custom tab under the product info parent tab- 
My layout.xml block code is :

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.faq" as="faq" template="catalog/product/view/faq.phtml">

    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>

    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>FAQ</value></action>

</block>
```

I created a custom attribute and  visible on frontend - YES - uesd in product listing - Yes
my attribute code is 'faq'
my faq.phtml is as follow -

```
<?php 

$_product = $this->getProduct();
if($_product->getFAQ()){ ?>

<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('faq')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>

<?php } 
?>
```

after doing a long exercise i am unable to display the attribute value on frontend. As I checked the data tables my attribute value are properly inserting in the attribute table. 
If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php if($_product->getFaq()){ ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getFaq();?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: tried with same code previously. but unable to view under the product- info tab. is there any css issue too?

Comment: if you put any static content in the template , is that visible in product-info tab?

Comment: Yes if am adding static block then it is displying.  I had cross-checked with a cms block it is displaying.

Comment: use `print_r($_product->getData()` and check are you getting faq value in that